# What's the difference between running heroku local and python manage.py

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am developing a web app and i want to have obviously local environment.
However I need to setup local env configs in my .env file and when I run `python manage.py runserver` it doesn't seem to load my env file, although `heroku local` does load it. Just to make sure I understand whats happening, id love to know what is the difference.

Comment: That is exactly the difference.

Comment: @DanielRoseman haha, well thank's a lot then  ! :)